# List ReportServer parameters for Report that run more that some average execution time

Tags: reporting-services

i am trying to get report parameters from ReportServer.dbo.Catalog table for reports that run more than average time of execution. So far i can calculate min.max,avg time of execution, but i am looking to check reports parameters that runs more then some average time.

```
    SELECT TOP 100 
               COUNT(*) TimesRun,
               c.[Name] ReportName,
               AVG(l.TimeDataRetrieval + l.TimeProcessing + l.TimeRendering) / 1000.0 [AverageExecutionTimeSeconds]            
FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog](NOLOCK) AS l
INNER JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog](NOLOCK) AS c ON l.ReportID = C.ItemID
WHERE c.Type = 2 -- Only show reports 1=folder, 2=Report, 3=Resource, 4=Linked Report, 5=Data Source
GROUP BY c.Name
HAVING AVG(l.TimeDataRetrieval + l.TimeProcessing + l.TimeRendering) / 1000.0 > 1
ORDER BY AVG(l.TimeDataRetrieval + l.TimeProcessing + l.TimeRendering) DESC;
```

How to combine this code , maybe like a stored procedure to get avg value for each report and also check what parameters were used when report exceeded avg value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do with the data and how you expect the output to look.

You could do something simple like CROSS APPLY a split function over the parameters column. Something like this will give you the parameters split over rows. It may not be what you need but hopefully will point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
               COUNT(*) TimesRun,
               c.[Name] ReportName,
               AVG(l.TimeDataRetrieval + l.TimeProcessing + l.TimeRendering) / 1000.0 [AverageExecutionTimeSeconds]            
            , p.[value] AS ParameterNameAndValue
    FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog](NOLOCK) AS l
        INNER JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog](NOLOCK) AS c ON l.ReportID = C.ItemID
        CROSS APPLY string_split(CAST(Parameters as varchar(max)),'&') p
    WHERE c.Type = 2 -- Only show reports 1=folder, 2=Report, 3=Resource, 4=Linked Report, 5=Data Source
    GROUP BY c.Name, p.[value]
    HAVING AVG(l.TimeDataRetrieval + l.TimeProcessing + l.TimeRendering) / 1000.0 > 1
    ORDER BY AVG(l.TimeDataRetrieval + l.TimeProcessing + l.TimeRendering) DESC
```

You could further split this into the parameter name and value I'm not sure what you really need.